# 1's Complement of 6 and 9

Tags: computer-science, binary

My question is related to 1's complement.
In the book it is mentioned that +6 is represented as 0110 and -6 as 1001 ( 1's complement of 6).

If the system is using the pattern 1001 to represent -6, then how will it represent 9, since the binary of 9 is also 1001?

Can someone please throw light on where I am missing on the logic.

Comment: You should restrict your post to one question and also show us some more context e.g. what is 1's compliment, how did you get $-6=1001_2$, what's stopping you from doing the samw thing with $9$, how are you getting $(+6)+(-6)=1111_2$, etc.?

Comment: As a hint to the last question, what is $-(1111_2)$ i.e. 1's compliment of your answer?

Comment: It depends on the range of integers you want your strings of bits to represent. When using 2's complement and four bits, the range you can cover is from $-8$ to $7$. Observe that $9$ is not in that range. If you use five bits instead, then $-6$ becomes $11001_2$. This time clashing with $25$, but that is ok given that with five bits you are covering the range $[-16,15]$, and $25$ is not in that interval.

Comment: Anyway, with $n$ bits you have $2^n$ strings of bits, so you can represent $2^n$ integers. Normal base $2$ expansions would give you $[0,2^n-1]$. Two's complement is just a way of covering $[-2^{n-1},2^{n-1}-1]$ instead, allowing negative integers to be represented as well. But, *the representation of a negative integer depends not only on the integer but also the number of bits in use.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that the number "width" in bits (the "word size") is given. So with 4 bits 3 bits can be used for the actual size of the number (its absolute value) and 1 bit (the leftmost) for its sign. With 3 bits we can go from -7 to 7 that way (with 0 having two representations, so the 16 bit strings are all used).

So +9 cannot be represented, unless we use more bits.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in one's complement, there are [two representations of zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement#Negative_zero) - $\overbrace{00\dots00}^{n\text{ zeroes}}$ and $\overbrace{11\dots11}^{n\text{ ones}}$ - when using $n$ bits to represent each number. Secondly, if we are using $n$ bits then the largest possible positive number that can be represented is $2^{n-1}-1$ so you cannot express $+9$ using $4$ bits as $2^{4-1}-1=7\lt9$.